# The property 'command' does not exist on the type 'Button'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

Error   1   The property 'command' does not exist on the type 'Button' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.    C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvvmLight2\Sample\MainPage.xaml    33  21  Sample

Comment: It helps if you post information about context and how you're using this, and not just an error message...

Answer (score 2):

You need to capitalize `Command` in your XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">
```